# Interesting behavior of preview

Tags: errors, compiling, compilation-error, preview

If you compile this code (note that `\begin{document}` is commented):

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
%\begin{document}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node  {a node}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You got this error:

```
! I can't find file `preview.aux'.
```

but if you uncomment `\begin{document}`, compile it again creating `preview.aux`:

```
\relax 
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

comment again `\begin{document}`, and eventually re-compile it, it works!

Why does it happen?

Comment: Interestingly! I expect that compilation of document without of `\begin{document}` will throw  error `missed \begin{document}`. When once is compiled the correct code, `.aux` code is created and than can be used at next compilation. Strange.

Comment: @Zarko Indeed, that's why I asked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error

```
 ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

has a rather simple implementation: it has been added to \everypar in the format:

```
 \everypar{\@nodocument}
```

So if something starts a paragraph in the preamble it is triggered.

It is easy to suppress the error, simply empty `\everpar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\everypar{} 
zzz

\begin{document}
aaa
\end{document}
```

Another way is to call `\@arrayparboxrestore` which contains an `\everypar{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter \@arrayparboxrestore \makeatletter
zzz

\begin{document}
aaa
\end{document}
```

The preview code contains at the begin a `\@arrayparboxrestore` and so it suppresses the error, but naturally if there is no `\begin{document}` important code is missing and so at the end you get an error that the aux-file is missing. Proving an aux helps here, but naturally that doesn't mean that you have a sane document.